# convert from word macro to C# If varObj.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then

Tags: c#, macos, office-interop

Trying to convert macro below to C#:

```
For Each varObj In ActiveDocument.Shapes
  If varObj.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
    n = n + 1
  End If
Next varObj
```

What I tried and does not compile:

```
foreach (Word.Shapes tempLoopVar_varObj in winword.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{
  if (tempLoopVar_varObj.Type == ord.WdInlineShapeType.msoEmbeddedOLEObject)
  {
   fileCount++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`winword.ActiveDocument.Shapes` actually returns iterator with underlying object of type `Word.Shape`. Try like this:

```
foreach (Word.Shape tempLoopVar_varObj in winword.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{
...
}
```

NOTE: The iterators / collections in word-iterop dll are not generic, but their name follow a common pattern. When you iterate over Word.Shapes then the underlying object is the same as the collection type but in singular naming -> Word.Shape.